# What is the effect of filling the Dragon Ball Meter?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-perfect-cell

**What is the effect of summoning Shenron?**

The rules regarding what happens when the Dragon Ball Meter is filled seem inconsistent.  The rulebook states the following (emphasis mine):

> Once the meter is completely filled, at the end of that round all active Z-Fighters are healed to their maximum health, **and all** KO'd Z-Fighters are revived and healed to their maximum health.

However, the character cards, which have quick-references explanations of some of the rules, state (emphasis mine):

> Place 7 Dragon Ball results on the Dragon Ball Meter to heal all Z Fighters to full HP, **or** revive **a** fallen Z Fighter.

(sic regarding one spelling "Z-Fighter" with a hyphen and one not)

The first ruling states that this effect heals everyone to full health, including all KO'd characters.  The second ruling states that you have a choice of either healing all non-KO'd characters, or healing one KO'd character.  **Which wording is correct?**

My assumption is that the second wording is correct, because the first wording from the rulebook is awkward; there would be no reason to say "heal all active characters AND heal all inactive characters" when you could just say "heal everyone, regardless of active status" if that is what you meant.  On the other hand, rulebooks are generally a more authoritative source than a quick-reference card.